# What was the sausage made of?

Tags: character, victorious

In S01E12 of *Victorious*, Sikowitz offered kids some sausages, Tori even ask him what it was made of but he laugh weirdly and never answered it. Even Robbie told other students about getting the same mad laugh in reply from Sikowitz about sausage.

I try googling about it but most of the speculations were about it being vegan or Sikowitz being a cannibal. But do we ever get any factual answer for it? On-screen or off-screen?

Comment: Apparently it was never established, but threads like these on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/victorious/comments/dubxr6/sikowits_is_a_cannibal/ - indicate that he's potentially a cannibal, so the sausage meat could be human.

Comment: Victoria Justice isn't a vegan or vegetarian, so out-of-universe, it was likely a genuine sausage.

Comment: @Valorum doesn't mean she can't eat vegan stuff.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - Yes, but we can immediately rule out that it can *only* have been a vegan sausage

Answer (score 1):

Sikowitz had a page on TheSlap.com, a viral website used to promote the show. He [posted several 'slaps'](https://victorious.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Posts_by_Sikowitz) that related to his cooking and food habits, but none that specifically confirmed what meat the sausage contained. It's likely that there wasn't a specific punchline here, just a setup for a [*mystery meat*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MysteryMeat) gag.

He posted about his homemade sausage

> **Sikowitz:** *Everyone wants to know what my homemade sausage is made out of. Hilarious, I know.*

And his 'vegan girlfriend'.

> **Sikowitz:** *My new vegan girlfriend is coming over for Thanksgiving dinner. I'm making a regular turkey, but I'm telling her it's vegan.*

And eating turkey

> **Sikowitz:** *Today is Thanksgiving?!? BRB—gotta go buy and stuff a turkey.*

And eating fish

> **Sikowitz:** *I'm currently trying to identify an object I found in my beard. I think it's tuna, but I haven't eaten sushi in days. Hmmmm....*